# Firefox add-on triggers code in each open window

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I have a Firefox add on that displays a pop-up when it sees a certain response header. This works fine when I have a single window. However, when I have multiple windows open, and one of the tabs in a window triggers the pop-up code in my add-on (due to the presence of said header) I get a pop-up in each of my open windows. For example, if I have 3 windows open, I get 3 different pop ups, one for each windows. Is this the default behavior, and is there an easy in-built way to fix this using their SDK.

Edit:
I have the following code:

```
Util.requestBlock(httpChannel) {
    /*load response headers here*/
    if (responseHeaders.includes("header_xyz"))
        alert("show popup");
}

Util.monitor = function(w) {
    this.obsService = Components.classes['@mozilla.org/observer-service;1'].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIObserverService);
    this.obsService.addObserver(this, 'http-on-examine-response', false);
}

Util.monitor.prototype = {
    'observe': function(subject, topic, data). {
        if (topic == 'http-on-examine-response'). {
            var channel = subject.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIHttpChannel);
            var block_response = new Util.RequestBlock(channel);
        }
    },
};
```

The Util.monitor adds an observer. Whenever a response is received, the "Observe" function is called.

Comment: Can you show some code, please?

Comment: Without code, this question may be off-topic: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working the way I want?**") must include: A) the desired behavior; B) a specific problem or error *and* C) **the shortest code necessary to reproduce it** all ***in the question itself***. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Answer (score 0):

```
var windows = require("window-utils");
for (window in windows.browserWindowIterator)
  doToWindow(window);
```